# Each new model comes with a "static" list of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure what the best way to describe this is (which is why I have had problems finding an answer on my own), but what I want to do is:

I have a model "Legislature", which each user can create.

Each legislature has several "committees". However, this list of committees needs to be the same for each legislature, and each has it's own set of columns with pre-set variables.

So I have:

Committee A
Committee B
Committee C

And each has it's own pre-determined fields. Each version of "legislature" will also have Committee A, Committee B, Committee C. As time moves on, each legislature's activities will dictate how the fields in the committees change, but of course, Committee A in one legislature may end up looking different than Committee A in another one.

How would I set this up? Alternately, if there is a term for what I am doing that I can use to google a solution, I would be fine with that as well!

Answer (score 0):

There are three Rails tools that may be of use: associations, callbacks, and scopes.

**Associations:** You can create a `Legislature` object and several `Committee` objects and leverage the `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations to reference these relationships. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

**Callbacks:** You can require that certain actions are taken at different points in an objects life cycle; this would allow for the creation of each requisite `Committee` when creating a `Legislature`. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html.

**Validations:** By pairing the `uniqueness` validation, you can ensure that a single `Legislature` does not have `Committee` objects with identical features (e.g. `name`); with the `scope` option, you can further allow multiple `Committee` objects to have the same feature, provided that they each `belong_to` a distinct `Legislature`. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Finally, this StackOverflow question may also be relevant: [Validate uniqueness of in association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965089/)